# magento2: what is difference between is_salable and is_in_stock?

Tags: magento2.4, out-of-stock, salable

I am confused between is_salable and is_in_stock field. in product listing page I  print `$product` object by `$product->getData()` and when I print this data there is a field called `is_salable`
I put somewhere condition for product isinstock or outof stock so can I check the product with like this condition `$product->getIsSalable()` ?

Your help would be appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

is_in_stock uses the status on the product, so you can change the stock status to out of stock, but still have qty available.

is_saleable is heavily used for grouped, bundle and configurable products and uses the event catalog_product_is_salable_after to return availability

Comment: is_salable internally check product stock status or product status ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Magento core code

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getIsSalable
```

The logic of the function says that if `getIsSalable` function exits or product has a value as `is_saleable` then the product is able to be purchased.

```
/**
     * Is product salable detecting by product type
     *
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsSalable()
    {
        $productType = $this->getTypeInstance();
        if (method_exists($productType, 'getIsSalable')) {
            return $productType->getIsSalable($this);
        }
        if ($this->hasData('is_saleable')) {
            return $this->getData('is_saleable');
        }

        return $this->isSalable();
    }
```

However, in this Magento Stackexchange, are some better explanation for what you are looking for:
[Differences between some stock methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159163/differences-between-some-stock-methods)